# Do I (single hiker) need to reserve Austrian and Italian mountain huts in advance(more than 3 days)?

Tags: hiking, alps, austria, italy

This year I want to spend a lot of time in Austrian and Italian mountains. I think I will do 2-4 day tours when there is weather window and then drive back to rest a bit and repeat.

I don't know how is it for solo hikers. Do they find some place for you, put you in winter room if everything is booked or not? For me it is really hard to plan precise dates and make reservations more months ahead. It is not that I wouldn't want to stick to the schedule. I just like sports hikes, which can last the whole day and I don't know where will I end, storm can mess things up.

In some countries they can't reject you and give you some place if you are just 1 person.

Thanks for info and wish you great summer!

Answer (score 4):

It is strongly recommended to make a reservation. On weekends, most huts will be booked full, often including the winter rooms. Near popular places, this can also happen during the week. So it is recommended to reserve as far ahead as possible. 3 days can work out during the week, sometimes it does not.
For most huts, it is possible to book a longer time in advance and cancel 2 days ahead without a cancellation fee if the weather is bad. So this is what I would recommend.

In general, you are unlikely to be turned away or forced to sleep outside at high altitude. However, some huts have become stricter due to people abusing this and the overcrowding that follows. The least thing you can do is calling the hut on the morning and ask whether there is still a place for you.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you do need to book in advance. Which month are you planning to go, 'cause it's gonna differ a lot. Some months you won't have issues without booking and some it's going to be booked for weeks in advance.